# git push --set-upstream vs --set-upstream-to

Tags: git, push

according to this [article](https://gist.github.com/miku/613ccf7a7030a6f32df1), `git push --set-upstream` is deprecated and `git push --set-upstream-to` should be used instead.

But when I checked the [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) documentation, I can only find `--set-upstream`, but `--set-upstream-to` is no where to be found.

So is `--set-upstream` deprecated? Should I use `--set-upstream` or `--set-upstream-to`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This mixes up `git branch` and `git push`.

The `git branch` command has both `--set-upstream` and `--set-upstream-to`, with the former deprecated in favor of the latter for the reason already given in [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581160/1256452).

The `git push` command has only `-u` aka `--set-upstream`, which takes no argument.  It means that if the push succeeds, your local Git should set, as the upstream of a branch reference supplied as your source, the remote-tracking branch corresponding to the destination branch you got the other Git to set, which in many cases, your own Git has just now created in *your* repository because their Git has also just created *their* branch.  (Whew!)

That is, suppose you have created a branch `newbranch`:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
... work, commit, etc
```

and want to set its upstream to `origin/newbranch`.  But if you try, it fails:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/newbranch
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/newbranch' does not exist
```

because `origin/newbranch` *does not exist yet*, because the other git at `origin` does not have a branch named `newbranch`.

Soon, however, you `git push` your local `newbranch` to their Git, so that their Git creates `newbranch` in *their* repository.  Now that they *do* have a `newbranch`, *your* Git creates your `origin/newbranch` to remember their `newbranch`.  And *now* you can use `git branch --set-upstream-to`, but it might be nice if `git push` could do that automatically—and that's the `git push --set-upstream`, aka `-u`, option.

It's *related to* `git branch --set-upstream-to`, but not the same.

Comment: ah, that cleared up my confusion. Thank you so much for helping out again!

Comment: MIne too! Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to understand what confusion `--set-upstream` can create ? The syntax of using it is clear enough. So why was it deprecated ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: I cannot expand any further on the reason already quoted (follow the link, or just scroll down to NickD's answer). The Git authors deemed it confusing, and deprecated it.

Comment: The mistake I made was I was typing it with a slash, but you can also type `git branch --set-upstream-to origin master`.

Comment: @PatPeter: that takes the name `origin` and turns it into a symbolic full name (run `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin` to see the result) and then sets the upstream of `master` to that name. As the name `origin` is normally short for `origin/master`, this is probably equivalent to `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`. That is, you're not setting the upstream of branch `newbranch`. You're setting the upstream of branch `master`.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your version of git. `--set-upstream-to` was introduced in 2012 in the 1.7.12-1.7.13 timeframe. Any version more recent than that should include it. This is what the commit said:

```
commit 6183d826ba62ec94ccfcb8f6e3b8d43e3e338703
Author: Carlos Martín Nieto <cmn@elego.de>
Date:   Mon Aug 20 15:47:38 2012 +0200

branch: introduce --set-upstream-to

The existing --set-uptream option can cause confusion, as it uses the
usual branch convention of assuming a starting point of HEAD if none
is specified, causing

    git branch --set-upstream origin/master

to create a new local branch 'origin/master' that tracks the current
branch. As --set-upstream already exists, we can't simply change its
behaviour. To work around this, introduce --set-upstream-to which
accepts a compulsory argument indicating what the new upstream branch
should be and one optinal argument indicating which branch to change,
defaulting to HEAD.

The new options allows us to type

    git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master

to set the current branch's upstream to be origin's master.
```

I would say it's not quite deprecated but it *is* discouraged. I don't know if it *was* deprecated more recently, but the fact the the `git-branch(1)` manpage for git-2.7.5 mentions it without warning about it, means it's still around and is going to stay around. You just have to be careful.

EDIT: sorry, it *is* deprecated in commit b347d06bf097aca5effd07871adf4d0c8a7c55bd, but these commits only mention `git-branch`, not `git-push`.

Comment: hi Nick, thanks for the answer! If I may ask, could you please tell me what is your search strategy when you were looking for the particular commit you mentioned in your answer? I mean the git repository for git contain thousands of commit, how could you find what you want?

Comment: I did `git log --grep=set-upstream-to` and looked at the last one (but I missed the next-to-the-last one which required the edit :-) )

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot about regular expression. thanks for letting me know. really appreciate it :)

Comment: The quote is helpful, but a beginner-level explanation of what it means would be even more helpful!